# Why do TS conditional returns require ambiguous casts over precise casts?

Tags: typescript, types, discriminated-union

I have a function which should conditionally return either an array of elements or a single element depending on the argument type

```
    get<T extends Base>(argument: Class<T>): T extends Child ? T[] : T {
        if (argument instanceof Child) {
            return this.arguments as T[]
        }
        return this.arguments[0] as T
    }
}
```

However, the `as T[]`, `as T` raise the alerts

```
Type 'T[]' is not assignable to type 'T extends Child ? T[] : T'.ts(2322)
```

```
Type 'T' is not assignable to type 'T extends Child ? T[] : T'.
  Type 'Foo' is not assignable to type 'T extends Child ? T[] : T'.ts(2322)
```

I *can* fix this by replacing them with `T extends Child ? T[] : T`

```
    get<T extends Base>(argument: Class<T>): T extends Child ? T[] : T {
        if (argument instanceof Child) {
            return this.arguments as T extends Child ? T[] : T
        }
        return this.arguments[0] as T extends Child ? T[] : T
    }
```

but that is repetitive, and actually seems less accurate and semantically descriptive to what the code is doing.

Why doesn't TS accept the `as T[]`, `as T`?

Comment: Because `Type 'T[]' is not assignable to type 'T extends Stackable ? T[] : T'` and the compiler is unable to verify that `T` itself has been narrowed to a subtype of `Stackable` via control flow analysis; see [ms/TS#33912](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/33912).  Does that fully address the question? If so then I'll write up a a full answer explaining. If not, what am I missing?

Comment: @jcalz Could we replace "*and*" with *"because*" there? As in, if the compiler *were* sophisticated enough to see that `T` has been narrowed, `T[]` *would* be assignable to the type? Or are these two separate issues? And yes, that fully addresses my question and I would appreciate and accept a full answer.

Comment: I guess if you think that `T` has in fact been narrowed then it would be "because", but such narrowing does not occur and in fact it is often incorrect to do so, which is why it hasn't been implemented.  I'll describe more in my answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Currently TypeScript cannot use [control flow analysis](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/narrowing.html#control-flow-analysis) to affect the apparent constraint of a [generic](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html) type parameter.  If you check a value `t` of a generic type `T`, the compiler might narrow the type of `t` to something narrower than `T`, but it will *not* do anything to `T` itself:

```
function foo<T>(t: T): T extends string ? "a" : "b" {
    if (typeof t === "string") {
        t // (parameter) t: T & string;
        return "a"; // error!
    }
    return "b"; // error!
}
```

Here `t` has been narrowed but `T` has not.  Since neither `"a"` nor `"b"` is assignable to `T extends string ? "a" : "b"` for generic `T`, both `return` lines produce an error.

---

It turns out not to be easy to implement some kind of control flow analysis on generic type parameters.  If you establish that `t` is a `string`, does it mean that `T` is some subtype of `string`? No.  `T` could be *wider* than `string`, or some type that overlaps with `string`.  All we know is that `T & string` is not `never`:

```
foo<unknown>("x"); // T is wider than string
foo<"x" | number>("x"); // T has overlap with string
```

This issue becomes even more apparent if there are multiple values of type `T`:

```
function bar<T>(t: T, u: T): void { }
bar<unknown>("x", 123);
bar<"x" | number>("x", 123);
```

Here you cannot use the fact that `t` is a `string` to conclude that `u` is a `string`.

There are times when it's safe to assume that the type of `t` can be used to reconstrain `T`, but identifying those and implementing it isn't trivial.  There have been various suggestions to try to support something like this, such as [microsoft/TypeScript#27808](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/27808) asking for a way to prohibit type arguments from themselves being unions, or [microsoft/TypeScript#33014](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/33014) asking for this behavior specifically when using generic keylike types and [indexed access types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/indexed-access-types.html).

The *general* suggestion is [microsoft/TypeScript#33912](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/33912) asking for some way to return generic conditional types.  It's been open for quite a while and although it continues to be discussed by the TypeScript team, it's not clear whether or not it will ever be addressed.

---

For now, all you can do is work around the problem by loosening the type checking.  You can use [type assertions](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#type-assertions), as you've seen.  This is a bit tedious if you have multiple return statements.  Another approach is to use a single-call-signature [overload](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/functions.html#function-overloads):

```
function foo2<T>(t: T): T extends string ? "a" : "b";
function foo2(t: unknown) {
    if (typeof t === "string") {
        return "a"; // okay
    }
    return "b"; // okay
}
```

This works because function overload implementations are checked fairly loosely against their call signatures. It's no safer than type assertions, just possibly more convenient.

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/GYVwdgxgLglg9mABMOcA8AVAfACigLkQwEpCNEBTADygrABMBnRRqAJxjAHNEB+RAEQBDAYkICARqIDeAKEQLEMYIjwBPAA4U4KqIgC8hwaw7cBxRHMXXEegPR3VGoWyEBbCrTYWCRRADIWdk4uAG55GwU2TxA2JGEBUMQHSjY2ODYAQgiFAF8cxGioWPipJJSKNIzs-NkUdHAAazA4AHcwXAEqc3LHchhmVph6StsACyEkExC61DQu0QAfRDAQNwlKzu7iXr8J5jgAN0qAGyENRCGoMaDTLlk68Gh4JAkXTFxfDAAaRBAyUiIQ5wYaWRD5N5sNBNFrtLYCX4ARgATABmHaySHzbqIZardabHALJFojEPUCQWAIZCoZEfPAAsiUGh0Ji3EJ8QQiMSCMqPSkvGlwZEMv5gZptMAWKyKZSqKCabS6AxGATTMzSgrWIolLmJZKOOCNIRqAr5bUxOK8-UpI0m2T5IA)